# Mediawiki: Ignoring wiki highlighting and just dumping in text

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, markup

I want to copy-paste an existing plain text into MediaWiki without any form of interpretation. However, the text contains characters that have a meaning in wiki markup, but I do not want wiki to do anything with it. I want wiki to just include it and do
the carriage return right. Both VERBATIM and NOWIKI cannot do that. Are there any other possiblities?

Here a snipplet of what I would like to enter:

```
#####################################################

          * bla bla *

bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla

          bla blabla bla - bla blabla bla 
               bla blabla bla
               bla blabla blabla
          https://twitter.com/bla bla

#####################################################

bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla
bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla

*bla bla bla bla
*bla bla
*bla blabla bla

#bla bla
#bla bla
#bla bla
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<nowiki>` does what you say you want: it ignores all markup and outputs the text exactly as you entered it. The problem with that is that HTML ignores newlines and considers multiple spaces as one.

What you actually want is [the `<pre>` tag](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aFormatting#HTML_tags).